# Achieving column freeze in Bootstrap tables

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, tabular

How do I freeze column in Bootstrap? I got a few columns to freeze. Something similar to Excel like the [pic](http://www.gcflearnfree.org/excel2013/17) below:

[image]

My manager says I am now allowed to use jQuery, even if it is jQuery component of Bootstrap. I therefore plan to write this in HTML, CSS and pure JavaScript. The least JavaScript shall be preferred.

Answer (score 1):

I've been in the same scenario, but I used jQuery plugin dataTables to fixed the left most column of the table.

Comment: i was supposed to comment this in your question but can't due to low reputation.

Comment: ok noted, but I have to use bootstrap without jquery, and my superior doesn't even want jquery component of bootstrap...

Comment: well, i'd say it's challenging to freeze a column scrolling vertically/horizontally. a lot says just use a plugin because it's complicated but give it a try, let me know if you done it. And try using jquery dataTables on a seperate file just to see.